# Compare 2 csv files with php and return changed row numbers

Tags: php, csv

I've script that compares 2 csv files and put changed row id's into array:

```
 //Function for comparing two files
 function row_compare($a, $b)
 {
 if ($a === $b)
 {
 return 0;
 }
 return (implode("",$a) < implode("",$b) ) ? -1 : 1;
 }

 //Set previous csv file
 $file1 = new SplFileObject("file1.csv");
 $file1->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

 //Set new csv file
 $file2 = new SplFileObject("file2.csv");
 $file2->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

 foreach ($file1 as $row)
 {
 $csv_1[] = $row;
 }

 foreach ($file2 as $row)
 {
 $csv_2[] = $row;
 }

 //Check differences
 $all_unique_rows = array_udiff($csv_1, $csv_2, 'row_compare');

 //Get rows id which have difference
 foreach($all_unique_rows as $key=>$unique_row)
 {
 foreach($unique_row as $element)
 {
 $rowwwithdiffer[] = array($key);
 }
 }
```

It works fine! But what I want to achieve - instead of getting 1, 2, 3 - use 1 - 3, it is - if changed rows are consecutive, use intervals instead of each changed row id...

how I can achieve it? ;-)

TNX!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run trough the array with the id's and check if they are consecutive and them deal with them accordingly.

```
$aglutinatedRows = [];
$lastRowId = $rowwwithdiffer[0];
$firstRowInSequence = $rowwwithdiffer[0];

foreach(array_slice($rowwwithdiffer, 1) as $row) {
    if ($row == $lastRowId + 1) {
        $lastRowId = $row;
    } else {
        $aglutinatedRows[] = $firstRowInSequence != $lastRowId ? $firstRowInSequence . ' - ' . $lastRowId : lastRowId;
        $firstRowInSequence = $row;
        $lastRowId = $row;
    }
}
```